# CSS Shifting from Images to Icons

Tags: css, icons

Suppose I have the following css. Now lately we've shifted to using fonts for spinners. So now I want to do is to replace the background with a icon.

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: url('images/spinner.gif') no-repeat center right;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: right;
}
```

This is what we do on the HTML side...

```
<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>
```

Is there a way to replace the top background with the bottom icon spinner definition?

Answer (score 0):

The later uses a [PNG sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) and if I'm correct your code is from [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) which comes with [Twitter BootStrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

Even though the markup uses the words icon does mean the format or method is any different than using a standard background, below is the code of `icon-arrow-down` using CSS.

```
.icon-arrow-down {
    background-position: -312px -96px;
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
    background-position: 14px 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 14px;
}
```

If you want to adopt the sort_asc.png image to a class of its own and not a table then just add something like:

```
.sort-asc {
background: url('images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do.  Let me try to be more clear.

Comment: You should be able to append the class name on the table to support this feature... `<th class="icon-arrow-down">`

Comment: But how do you do this in CSS?